# DataTables serverside processing Hangs

Tags: jquery, datatables

got some issues in dataTables I hope you can help me. after requesting it renders the table with the correct data but searching, pagination and entry filters are not working plus the whole page is not responding.

code:

```
function generate (table, action, verb, columns,func) {
    var table = $(table).DataTable({
        "serverSide": true,
        "processing": true,
        "ajax": {
            "url": action,
            "type": "post",
            "datatype": "json"
        },
        "columns": columns
    });
```

Comment: Check the console for `searching, pagination`, must be some error.

Comment: already checked that but no errors appears in console

Comment: When you set `"serverSide": true` all the paging and searching must be handled by the server-side code. Are you doing that? Please show the query that does the database lookup.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was I was loading the whole records like around 70 thousand data in the first load of the page in effect Data Table got lag. And I realized that when server side is set to true, searching, paging and filtering are handled on the server side. Data tables is posting some data that are essential in order for it to work properly such as draw, start, length, etc. So in the first load data tables will post start = 0, length  depends on the entries needed to display (i.e. 10,25,50,100 records to display) and when i got that information to my back end, I NEED  to load 10 or 25 or 50 or 100 records depending on the length that is posted. Hope someone can help this solution